# Notepad++, take it easy on nonexistent folder

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ constantly. We have a lan where we store things. However, most of our clients have vpns which I constantly have to connect to and lose my lan access temporarily. When I do this, every file that is open in notepad++ takes an annoying half-minute at a seemingly "not responding" state, after which it asks if I should keep a copy of it open.

Is there some way to tell it to ignore the accessibility of its storage folder until I hit save?

Comment: If you disable the option `use default gateway in remote network` in your VPN ipv4 advanced settings, your local network should stay accessible. The disadvantage of this is that you can no longer do DNS queries on the remote host. Usually this is not required anyway, and if that's the case, it is a far better solution to disable this option. You will be able to do everything on IP address still.

Answer (score 2):

You could try going to Settings \ Preferences, then in the MISC tab look for the "File Status Auto-Detection" section, and set it to "Disabled".

**Edit**: This is the function in Notepad++ which periodically checks for changes or disappearance of a file opened in notepad, and throws up the popup you want to get rid of. If you disable this automatic checking, then Notepad++ will not complain about missing files (only on save if your networked drive is not connected, because the path where you want to save it does not exist).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: Edited more information into the answer.